# RescaleOP only applying to half of the image?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I am using the rescaleOP class to increase brightness/contrast of an image. My code is here

```
RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp(1.2f, 15, null);
rescaleOp.filter(image, image);  // Source and destination are the same.
```

However, this only applies to half of the BufferedImage. How would I get this to apply to the whole image?

Comment: Your code works for me... Perhaps you are doing something odd somewhere else in your code, that causes this? Or perhaps there's a bug in your Java implementation... What JRE are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I was using Java 9 somehow, but I changed it to java 8 and it worked. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If the problem persists with more recent versions of Java, I hope you report a bug!

Comment: Same issue with jdk1.8.0_271. Fixed when I change it to jdk1.8.0_301.